# Backtrace JavaScript DOM Insert

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a page that has several (20+) scripts that are being loaded. One of them is inserting an iframe into the DOM. Using the Chrome developer tools, is there anyway I can figure out when/where/how that iframe is being inserted into the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Firebug's [break on mutate](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Break_On_Mutate). Otherwise you could disable one script after another an check when the iframe isn't insert anymore.